# How install Integration Services in sql-2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, ssis-2005

I need to install the SQL component Integration Services is to create ETL but the component is disabled, How can I install it?

[image: this image]

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Windows 7?  Window Server?  XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to install Enterprise or Standard editions which cannot be installed on a desktop operating system (like Vista , 7 ...). Try using the SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition instead.